# Encrypt CC on server without Decryption possibility only on in-house server

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

we would like to step-up our credit card security on our web server.

Currently we are using AES which is a [Symmetric-key algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).
we are not too happy, since if compromised the thief will have access to the decryption key.

We are thinking of switching to asymmetric cryptography ([Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)) so the decryption key will not be stored on this web server. but it seems to me that this type of encryption are not as secure as the symmetric one.

**Q1: Does it make sense 2 combine the 2?**

I would do as follows.

on web-server

1. Encrypt credit card with symmetric encryption Encrypt it again with
2. asymmetric encryption - public key

in Secure environment.

1. Decrypt w/ asymmetric encryption - public key
2. Decrypt w/ symmetric encryption

**Q2: is it indeed true that asymmetric cryptography is less secure than Symmetric-key algorithm?**

Comment: *"it seems to me that this type of encryption are not as secure as the symmetric one."* only if you are concerned with quantum computers and their ability to factor large numbers fast (not really, because they are not usable now).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not directly related to programming. These two questions would be much better suited for [security.se].

Comment: **Q1:** You should have done that a long time ago. Yes, that's the way to go. **Q2:** They are equally secure today if you use equivalent (not equal!) key sizes. Quantum computers could break RSA much faster than classical computers, but there aren't any today (that we know of). See also: [Encryption - should I be using RSA or AES?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/encryption-should-i-be-using-rsa-or-aes)

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB.! im a bit confused about your last comment. 
1. first you are saying the double encryption is the way to go, 
1. then you say "they are equally secure" 
if so what's the point in double encrypting?

Comment: (1) I wouldn't call it double encryption, because RSA and AES are used for different things, but you need AES to encrypt something big with RSA. If you're sending stuff between two parties then you *need* some kind of asymmetric encryption such as RSA. (2) Despite their different use cases, you can their determine key sizes for RSA and AES that where brute-forcing such as key would take an equal amount of time. Example: 2048-bit RSA would be equivalent to a 128-bit AES key (I haven't looked up those numbers, so they are probably wrong).